# How to make an average of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, average

This is for my GCSE Computer Science. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var middaytemp = []; midnighttemp = [];
for (count = 0; count <= 29; count++) {
middaytemp[count] = prompt("What was the temperature at midday");
midnighttemp[count] = prompt("what was the temperature at midnight?");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += middaytemp[count] + "&deg; Celcius<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += midnighttemp[count] + "&deg; Celcius<br>";
}
</script>
</html>
```

As you can see it asks these two questions 29 times each. I've got them in an array but I need to find the average of the array. so when the temperatures are put in at the end of the code it shows the average for the night and average for the day.

Comment: Those questions are asked thirty times each. But where are you stuck? What part(s) do you not understand how to implement?

Comment: `Celsius`, not `Celcius`

Comment: Yeah I know. That was a typo. I need to find the average and output it. Thanks again. Luke

Comment: Sum the values inside the `for` loop with something like `middaytotal` and `midnighttotal`. Then after the loop you calc the average, no aditional loops or functions are needed.

Comment: Which average? Arithmetic? Geometric? Harmonic? Power? A composition of them, e.g.: arithmetic-geometric (AGM)? Median? Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the results via following

```
var sumTempDay = 0;

for (var i = 0 ; i < middaytemp.length; i++) {
   sumTempDay += middaytemp[i];

}

var avgTempDay = sumTempDay/middaytemp .length;

var sumTempNight = 0;

for (var i = 0 ; i < midnighttemp.length; i++) {
   sumTempNight += midnighttemp[i];

}

var avgTempNight = sumTempNight/midnighttemp.length;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped. I'll do that. Where do I put the prompt("whats the temp at midday"). Sorry. I'm new to this. Thanks. Luke

Comment: where do i put the prompt where i ask the temp? sorry i'm new to this. Thanks. Luke

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)! This will return the sum of `midday` into `sum`.

```
let sum = midday.reduce((x,y) => x+y);
sum = sum/midday.length; //average
```

I used a an ES6 feature here called a `lambda expression` or "fat arrow function". It is the lexical equivalent of an anonymous function, which is used as the callback parameter for the array `reduce` function.

```
var sum = midday.reduce(function(x,y) {
    return x+y;
});
```

With a lambda expression, the return is implied, which is why you only need `=> x+y`. Multiple lines would require `{ ... }`. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for arrow function syntax.

Comment: Look at the OP's code; you need to explain what `Array.prototype.reduce()` does, and what arrow functions are, and how they work.

Comment: Slight point of clarification "With a lambda, the return is implied", should probably say something like "With a single expression lambda".

Comment: or just remove all of that from the answer, leaving the last snippet since the rest is irrelevant, *evil grin*

Comment: @KevinB you get out of here! Go on, get!

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the array, since your values are strings, they have to be converted to an integer first. And average is just the sum of values divided by the number of values.

```
var sum = 0; for( var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++ ){ sum += parseInt( elmt[i], 10 ); //don't forget to add the base } var avg = sum/elmt.length; document.write( "The sum of all the elements is: " + sum + " The average is: " + avg );
```

Comment: How do you iterate through the array? Could you give an example? Thanks again. Luke

Comment: var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++ ){
    sum += parseInt( elmt[i], 10 ); //don't forget to add the base
}

var avg = sum/elmt.length;

document.write( "The sum of all the elements is: " + sum + " The average is: " + avg );

Comment: ^sorry - not used to using the correct formatting. I hope it still makes sense.

Comment: @RichardDickins you should edit that into your answer, not as a comment so that it's easier to read.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Cheers. Is there any way to send a direct message to one user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the string into float. Then calculate the average.

```
var sum = 0
middaytemp.forEach(function(val){
    sum += parseFloat(val);
})
var average = sum/middaytemp.length;
```